# How can I generate user feedback in the Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I've got a model for scheduling players in games in which I want the scheduler to be able to keep track of size and other attributes of the roster.

I've created some custom validation that works reasonably well when roster rules are violated (i.e., too many or too few players scheduled.) But I also want to provide feedback when the roster doesn't violate rules.

I've been trying to insert a message with message_user in various ways. The closest I have come to success is with this:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.save()
    count = obj.players.count()
    self.message_user(request,"Players scheduled: %s" % count)
```

The problem is that the feedback message doesn't update to the correct count on the first click of "Save" or "Save and continue editing". A user has to click a second time to get the current count.

Maybe the save_model method isn't the best way to do this, but I've tried a couple others (queryset, change_view) with even less success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Added form.save_m2m() after obj.save().

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    count = obj.players.count()
    self.message_user(request,"Players scheduled: %s" % count)
```